# inheritance another class attributes in model class

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

While creating database, we have to write some attributes in every tables like (status, registerd_by, registered_dt). So is there any way in django that I create a separete class for these fields and inherit this class in another classes. For example,

Creating a `common` class,

```
class Common(models.Model):     
    registerd_by = models.CharField(max_length = 10)    
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    registered_dt = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

class Users(models.Model): 
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    
class Patients(models.Model):     
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

How to `inherit` the `Common` class in these two classes such that the attributes of the Common classes will also become member of these two classes. In this way, I don't have to write the repeating fields in all my classes.

Answer (score 1):

Make the **Common** Model an abstract Model class and then inherit the **Common** abstract class in **Users** and **Patients** Model, as shown below.

```py
class Common(models.Model):     
    registerd_by = models.CharField(max_length = 10)    
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    registered_dt = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Users(models.Model, Common): 
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    
class Patients(models.Model, Common):     
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```